# How can I force individually required lodash modules into a vendor chunk with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, lodash, javascript-build

I am requiring lodash modules individually, so that my JS build contains only the lodash code that I need (e.g. `import map from 'lodash/map'` instead of `import _ from 'lodash'`. (Actually, I'm using [babel-plugin-lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-lodash) to automate this.) So nowhere in the code do I actually import the whole of `'lodash'`.

I would like webpack to put any lodash code that needs to be included into a vendor bundle. Following [the webpack examples out there](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code) for splitting vendor and app bundles, I know how to include *all* of lodash in the vendor bundle (using the CommonsChunkPlugin). But I don't want to just use `'lodash'` as an entry point and pull in the whole library. Instead, I want to make all the modules that I actually import that start with `lodash` to end up in the vendor bundle.

Any ideas?

**Addition**

The situation is further complicated by the fact that I build 3 bundles for each app: a vendor bundle, a bundle of stuff common across apps (which will use lodash modules), and the app-specific code (which will also use lodash modules).

Here are the key parts of my webpack config:

```
// ...
entry: {
  specificApp: specificAppEntry,
  appCommon: [appCommonEntry],
  vendor: [listOfVendorJsLibraries],
},
// ...
plugins : [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    names: ['appCommon', 'vendor'],
    minChunks: Infinity,
  }),
  // ...
],
// ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a `minChunks` function to implement custom logic: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin

You could use this to check if the module being imported is coming from `node_modules/lodash`.

e.g. I use the following to pull *everything* imported from `node_modules` into a `vendor` bundle:

```
import path from 'path'

import webpack from 'webpack'

new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'vendor',
  minChunks: function (module, count) {
    return (
      module.resource &&
      module.resource.indexOf(path.resolve('node_modules')) === 0
    )
  }
})
```

---

Working solution for use with `CommonsChunkPlugin`, as posted in a comment:

```
  minChunks: function(module, count) {
    return module.resource && module.resource.indexOf('lodash') !== -1
  }
```

Comment: I added a config snippet above. As you see my use of the CommonsChunkPlugin involves two different entries, appCommon and vendor, and I lodash modules only to go into vendor. How can I do that with the minChunks funciton?

Comment: Seems like if I return `true` from the `minChunks()` function the module is sent up the tracks to the last chunk in my CommonsChunks array. So the following seems to do what I need: `minChunks: function(module) { var isLodashModule = module.resource && module.resource.indexOf('lodash') !== -1; if (isLodashModule) { return true; } return false; }`

Comment: If you want to amend the answer I think we have it.